# Array to Json Format in Deluge

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

How do you convert array to a JSON Format in Deluge?

The return of response is a array.

```
response = zoho.creator.getRecords("zoho_user12586", "pilmico-duplicate", "Add_New_Employee_Record_Report", "", 1, 1000, "creator_auth");
```

Comment: Please post the response and clarify what do you want to do

Comment: There is no error there. the return here is an array. can this make it into a  json format rather than an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make a post request:

```
header_data = {"Content-Type":"application/json"};
response = response.toText();
req = postUrl("URL",response,header_data);
```